# how to pass argument to Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: html, dynamic, backbone.js, marionette

how to pass a values dynamically to an Marionette.CompositeView during run time? like in java we create a method like the following

```
package com.test.poc;

public class SampleMethod {
    public int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleMethod method = new SampleMethod();
        int firstValue = 90, secondValue = 90;
        System.out.println("add : " + method.add(firstValue, secondValue));

    }
}
```

the above is the simple java code anybody can understand like the above how to create and pass arguments to `Marionette.CompositeView` and work on them?

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks to the person who gave down vote with out even giving the reason. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at the moment you instanciate a view, you can pass whatever arguments you want. normally you pass the model and the collection to be rendered in the compositeView, but you can pass more data if you need.

```
 var MyCompositeView = Backbone.Mationette.CompositeView.extend({
     initialize : function (options){
        this.dataValue = options.dataValue1;
        this.helperObject = options.helperObject;
        this.useValues();
     },
     useValues: function () {
       console.log(this.dataValue);
     }

 });

 var helperObject = { 
     value3 : "I have a value",
     value4 : "I dont!"
 }; /// a js object literal

 var myModel = new MyModel();
 var myCollection = new MyCollection();
 var myCompositeView = new MyCompositeView({model:myModel,
                                            collection:myCollection,
                                            helperObject:helperObject,
                                            dataValue1:"Hi there"});
```

notice that Im passing 4 values in the at the time to intanciate the view, and Im reading just two of them, the model and the collection will be handled by marionette, but the other two you can read them in your initialize function.

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the post,I will try my best to use your answer. I am very new to backbone.marionette. This is what is my problem `i am trying to customize a HTML table. So if i have a composite view which takes the collection,and an item view and the header names it will be easy for others to extend my composite view and pass their collection and itemview and model` I really don't know how to do this. would you please help me to do this also please create jsfiddle if possible which will help me to understand even more better. Thanks a lot and +1 for the post  :)

Comment: Hi Rayweb Please have a look at this question also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672838/how-to-construt-template-for-composite-view-dynamically