# How to construct template for Composite view Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, marionette

Desired output :

```
  <script id="table-template" type="text/html">
      <table>
        <thead>
           ADD THE HEADER NAMES HERE DYNAMICALLY,
        </thead>        
        <!-- insert collection items -->
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </script>
```

I am trying to get the above template generated, the problem here is the header names

Portfolio
        Amount
        Exchange
        Amount in Fccy
        Quantity
        Account

like the above it would be the fixed one, the user can give any number of header names.

This is the Code i have done :

```
Grid.Hexgrid = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
         template: "#header", 
         initialize : function (options){
           this.header = options.header;
        },
        onRender : function(){
            ADD THE HEADER INFORMATION HERE WHICH WILL COME UNDER <THEAD></THEAD>
        },

      appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
        collectionView.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);
      }
    });
```

I have given my comments in `BOLD` letter. would somebody help me to complete this Please.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set the template properties in your view, as the function getTemplate would do that for you.

Anyway to generate your header dinamically I suggest you another route, to just pass your header's data to your template like that:

```
serializeData: function() {
    var data = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.serializeData.apply(this, arguments);
    data.header = this.header;
    return data;
}
```

And then in your template you could do:

```
<% _.each(header,function(h){ %>
    <div class="span2"><%= h %></div>
<% }); %>
```

Comment: Very kind of you. It is working fine, is there any way that we can do this without specifying in template ? like can we iterate the header names in the  script itself?.

Comment: I suppose you can generate the header's html as a string in a function of your view and then assign it to a value in serializeData method like: data.header = this.formatHeader();
So in your template you can simply print the raw html: <%- header %>. Anyway I prefer to iterate it in the template, for such a small logic it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is done using the following way :

```
onRender : function() {
            headerInformation = this.header;
            for ( var column in headerInformation) {
                this.$("tr").append("<th>" + headerInformation[column] + "</th>");
            }
        }
```

Best Regards